# where are custom permissions for a SharePoint list saved? (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am developing a POC (SahrePoint 2010) where I can demonstrate that the users can be granted certain permissions on a list for a Date range (for example contribute access for a selected week). I will be breaking permission inheritance and create unique permissions for a list.
I would like the permissions to be revoked automatically after the expiry date. Also, I would like to do this using the Manage Permissions list (_layouts/user.aspx) so that I don't have to maintain a separate list.

I have a couple of questions regarding this:
1. I assume that the custom permissions for any list must be stored n some list. How can get to know in which list the permissions are getting stored?
2. If at all I get to know in which list the permissions are getting stored, will I be able to add columns to that particular list?

I hope that the question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions are not stored in any list. Rather, every securable object (including sites, lists, folders, and items) has a **Role Assignments** property that indicates what groups/users currently have access, and what their permissions are (if not inherited).

See the **[SPRoleAssignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.sproleassignment.aspx)** class documentation for more information.

Note that the User Information list is not a "Manage Permissions" list; it stores profile information about users who access the site, but does not store any permission-related information. Further, it's not a typical list at all, in that it does not show up in the `SPWeb.Lists` collection for a subsite, and its fields are automatically populated by SharePoint's User Profile Service. While you could potentially add more columns to it, you'd be better off using a separate list to store and track your permission information instead of contaminating the site collection user info list.

To have permission changes take place based on an expiry date, you'll need to implement a time-based solution that runs on a regular basis to see if any changes need to be made, such as a custom timer job, a custom site workflow that runs on a schedule, or a Windows scheduled task.

Comment: I have got a similar feedback from 2 other sources. Thanks!